# How can I double the integer and update them?

Tags: c

Currently, with your help I was able to solve the problem of option 1 and now I have to double the 'score.dat' file's integer and update them. I was able to get the value of double but I have no idea how to update them in 'score.dat' I am guessing that I have to use fwrite() function but not really sure.

[image]

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen("score.dat", "rb");

    int input;
    int number [20] = {0};
    int doubler = 0;


    while (input != 3)
    {
        printf("1. Read and display all data from 'score.dat' \n");
        printf("2. Multiply all the numbers in 'score.dat' by 2. \n");
        printf("3. Quit. \n");
        printf("Enter your option: ");

        scanf("%d", &input);

        printf("\n");

        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                fread(&number, sizeof(int), 20, filepointer);
                printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", number[0], number[1], number[2], number[3], number[4], number[5], number[6], number[7], number[8], number[9], number[10], number[11], number[12], number[13], number[14], number[15], number[16], number[17], number[18], number[19]);
                printf("\n");
                printf("\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    filepointer = fopen("score.dat", "wb");

                    doubler = number[i] + number[i];
                    number[i] = doubler;
                    fwrite(&number[i], sizeof(int), 1, filepointer);
                }
                printf("\n");

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `doubler = number[i] + number[i]; number[i] = doubler;` could be written `number[i] *= 2;`

Comment: You open the file twice, once at the very beginning of main, and once in `case 2`, and you never close it. Start cleaning that up first.

Comment: you mean at option 1 I have to declare fclose()?

Comment: Why would you expect anything different from what you had? you initialised the array `number` to zeros. so multiplied by 2 you still get zeros!

Comment: ... and your printf should be done with a loop.

Comment: Please do not post pictures. Post text as text.

Comment: @JungJaeWon cleaning up your file opening mess = If you want to read from the file: open it, do the read, close it (using fclose). If you want to write to the file: open it, do the write, close it (using fclose).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Got it. I have changed it

Comment: In case 2, the code opens the file 20 times. You definitely don't want to do that.

Comment: @PhoenixBlue The screenshot at the top of the question shows that the array is not filled with zeros when option 2 is chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the data, based on previous values, you want to

- Open the file in update mode ("r+")
- Read the existing data
- Change the numbers are needed.
- Write the data to the beginning of the file

  ```
  case 2:

  filepointer = fopen("score.dat", "r+");
  // Add Error check - if (filepointer != NULL ) ...

  // Read
  fread(&number, sizeof(int), 20, filepointer);

  // Update
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) number[i] *= 2 ;

  // Write the data to the beginning of the file
  rewind(filepointer) ;
  fwrite(&number[i], sizeof(int), 20, filepointer);

  // Close file
  fclose(filepointer) ;
  ...
  ```